# Not able to put space between search form and menu in css

Tags: html, css

Here is my [***jsfiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/nm9wutnz/) (without design)

Not able to put space between the search form and menu.

I need, as in the home link have some space before the menu.. the search form need to put some space after the menu.

```
#search-ams {
    background: #FFF none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
    border: 1px solid #CACACA;
    width: 213px;
    height: 24px;
    float: right;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

I tried to put padding value.. but if I add `padding-right:5px;` .. search form moved down in the menu.

Can anyone help me to fix this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use `margin` to space elements out:

```
#search-ams {
    float: right;
    background: #FFF none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
    width: 213px;
    height: 24px;
    border: 1px solid #CACACA;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nm9wutnz/9/)

Comment: if i use margin-top:20px; it didn't change from down position in the menu.. but if i add margin-top: -27px; ..it will be correct position.. so how can i omit negative value..thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by saying "didn't change from down position in the menu", but if you use negative `margin-top`, your search bar jump up, which is pretty normal behaviour. Now question is where do you want to move your search bar - to the top, to the right, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I can't be 100% sure I understand exactly what you're asking, but assuming you just want to put some distance between the menu and the search box, wouldn't simply adding something like:

```
margin-top: 10px;
```

To #search-ams do the trick?

Though if this was all you needed, I'm guessing you'd probably have figured that out yourself :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `margin`.
margin clears the area around element. We can give top, right, bottom, and left margin to the element.

we can give different margins from different side as:

```
element{
margin-top: 10px;
margin-bottom: 12px;
margin-right: 15px;
margin-left: 20px;
}
```

we can use shorthand property:

```
element{
margin: 10px 15px 12px 20px;   <!-- Top,Right,Bottom, Left respectively -->
}
```

If margin is same from all sides, we can simply give as:

```
element{
margin: 10px; 
}
```